# Prove $ e^n$ is not $O(n^{2017})$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, asymptotics

I'm trying to prove that $ e^n $ is not $ O(n^{2017}) $  using the definition of Big Oh. Here's what I've got so far:

Suppose $ e^n \le c*n^{2017} $ for some constant $ c > 0 $.
By the Maclaurin series for $ e^n $, we have:

$ 1 + n + \frac{n^2}{2!} + \frac{n^3}{3!} + ... \le c*n^{2017} $

But $ \frac{n^{2018}}{2018!} \le 1 + n + \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n^3}{6} + ... $ , so $ \frac{n^{2018}}{2018!} \le c*n^{2017} $ by transitivity of $\le$.

Dividing through by $ n^{2017} $ gives $ \frac{n}{2018!} \le c $ and hence $ n \le c*2018! $.

But $ f(n) = n $ is an unbounded increasing function, so eventually $ n \ge c*2018! $ for some constant $ c $.

Contradiction - hence $ \frac{n^{2018}}{2018!} $ is not $ O(n^{2017}) $, which implies $ e^n $ is not $ O(n^{2017}) $.

Is my argument correct?

Comment: Look ok to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all looks correct, except for some small details. One problem is here:

> But $f(n)=n$ is an unbounded increasing function, so eventually $n≥c∗2018!$ for some constant $c$

The problem is "for some constant $c$". You should actually say "for every constant $c$". If you don't specify this, then there's a possibility that the $c$ value you choose here isn't the same $c$ you chose earlier.

Another problem is this: The definition of $f(n)=O(g(n))$ is $$\exists c,\exists k,\forall n\ge k,f(n)\le c\cdot g(n)$$

You didn't make any mention of the fact that the inequality only needs to hold for all $n\ge k$ for some $k$.